# How to open specific activity for particular id by clicking from external link

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I added App link assistant in my app to open particular activity from an external link. Now I've the following code in my DataDetailActivity.

```
   Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
    Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
    if(appLinkData != null)
    {
        String dataId = appLinkData.getLastPathSegment();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, DataDetailActivity.class);
        startActivity(resultIntent);

    }
```

I would like to open particular DataDetailActivity. But this does throws error. Where do I have to pass dataId in the intent?

Note: We have Default HomeScreen in the app that has Login To FB button. So Do I have to write down this code in HomeScreenActivity and pass intent to DatadetailAcvity.java? If yes then how Do I tell to DataDetailScreen for particular data(If i have id)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**manifests.xml**

```
<application
    ....
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".HomeScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="somescheme" />  <!--This line to define schema -->
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

 ....
</application>
```

**HomeScreenActivity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    checkDeepLink();
}

private void checkDeepLink(){
    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getData() != null) {
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        String scheme = data.getScheme();
        String host = data.getHost();
        String param = data.getQuery();
        Log.d("DeepLink","Schema : " + scheme);
        Log.d("DeepLink","Host : " + host);
        Log.d("DeepLink","param : " + host);

        if (host.equals("page_details")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,DatadetailAcvity.class);
            intent.putExtra("detail_id",Long.valueOf(data.getQueryParameter("detail_id")));  // URL query values as string, you need to parse string to long.
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
          // ... other logic
        }
    }
}
```

**DeepLink**

```
scheme://host?pama_name=value&other_param_name=value
```

**Example:**

```
 somescheme://page_details?detail_id=2
```

**Facebook** [Step-by-Step Guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/deep-linking/)

**Update**

**DatadetailAcvity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data_detail);
    if (getIntent() !=null) {
        long detailId = getIntent().getLongExtra("detail_id",-1);

        if (detailId != -1){
            // do your stuff and displayed page by id
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to do anything in DataDetailActivity?

Comment: It is actually scenario where app has multiple locations details and clicking on it shows details for that loc(DataDetailActivity here). So I want to display DataDetailActivity for that perticular loc(As we are getting id from link). So How Could I get iit in DataDetailActivity.

Comment: One of the API doc says /api/loc/list/:ID to get a single tour. Idk if this is helpful in this case or not just sharing it.

Comment: Check my update to obtain `detail_id` from `DataDetailActivity`,

Comment: Also check my comment on parse string query url to long **URL query values as string, you need to parse string to long.**

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot.  It does open Detail Screen Successfully now if app is already running in background. But if not I got error Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onStart()' on a null object reference

Comment: I do have tMapView = findViewById(R.id.map); and  tMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState); in Oncreate() though. Do you think that it is not able to load in short time or something !!

Comment: You need to put your logic inside `onMapReady` [Check maps  doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start)

Comment: It still doesn't work for FB though. It opens link in browser and If I press ... from right top corner then it has option Open in App. I does not want that instead I just want to open directly app. I've added FB sdk and updated FB app setting.Why does it show open in app in option menu and does not directly just open app?

Comment: I open another issue. If you could help me with it please. https://stackoverflow.com/q/53330464/8490218

Answer (score 0):

Without error info,but if you want pass data through deep linking, you could use query parameters.
Suppose url is `https://www.example.com/example?param1=hello`

Then

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
String param1 = data.getQueryParameter("param1");
```